# Implicit differentiation for the following function

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Finding the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for $x^y=y^x$, I noticed that in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548339/did-i-take-the-derivative-correctly-xy-yx) it took the log of both sides and then it implicitly differentiates, thus we have: $$y\ln(x) = x \ln(y).$$ 
But isn't that wrong since we are changing the function to something different?

---

Wouldn't the correct step be to take the log and exponential since that would not change the function to a different one, i.e. $$e^{y \ln (x)}= e^{x \ln (y)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with taking the logarithm of both sides because the question is not about each individual side but the relationship between $y$ and $x$ which, is maintained even as the sides themselves are transformed.

However, you also don't have to take the logarithm.  There is a rule, the "generalized power rule", that you can use for any $a^b$ type of relationship.  The generalized power rule is:

$$d\left(a^b\right) = b\,a^{b - 1}\,da + \ln(a)\,a^b\,db $$

Note that this is a simple linear combination of the power rule and the exponent rule.  Applying this to your problem, you get:

$$ d\left(x^y\right) = d\left(y^x\right) \\
y\,x^{y - 1}\,dx + \ln(x)\,x^y\,dy = x\,y^{x - 1}\,dy + \ln(y)\,y^x\,dx \\
\ln(x)\,x^y\,dy - x\,y^{x - 1}\,dy = \ln(y)\,y^x\,dx - y\,x^{y - 1}\,dx \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\ln(y)\,y^x - y\,x^{y - 1}}{\ln(x)\,x^y - x\,y^{x - 1}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The exponential function is one-to -one. Hence there is no difference between $e^{y\ln x }=e^{x \ln y}$ and $y \ln x=x \ln y$.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: $e^{x}$ is one-to-one because its derivative is $e^{x}$ which is always $>0$. @Robben

Comment: That part I understand but why does it being one to one make it equivalent to $y\ln(x)=x\ln(y)$?

Comment: What is the definition of a one-to-one function? If $f$ is one-to-one then $f(a)=f(b)$ implies $a=b$. That is the definition . @Robben

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathrm{e}^z$ is injective, your last display is equivalent to your first display.

That a function, $f$, is injective means that for all $u,v$ in the domain of $f$, if $f(u) = f(v)$, then $u = v$.  This property is also called "one-to-one", where the sense of this phrase is "to each element, $y$, of the image of $f$, there is exactly one element in the domain of $f$, $x$, such that $f(x) = y$."

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, doing the same thing on both sides doesn't change the function. You can check this:
$$x^y=y^x$$
$$y=\log_{x}(y^x)$$

And then changing the base of the log to $e$ (which gives us $\ln(x)$

$$y=x\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(x)}$$
$$y\ln(x)=x\ln(y)$$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps to address your concern about altering the differentiation, you argue that the "first step" ought to be
$$ e^{\ y \ln (x)} \ \ = \ \ e^{ \ x \ln (y)} \ \ . $$
But then we would differentiate this as
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \ [ \ e^{y \ln (x)} \ ] \  \ = \ \ \frac{d}{dx} \ [ \ e^{x \ln (y)} \ ]  \ \  \Rightarrow \ \  e^{y \ln (x)} · \frac{d}{dx} \ [ \  y \ \ln (x)  \ ] \  \ = \ \ e^{x \ln (y)} · \frac{d}{dx} \ [ \  x \ \ln (y)  \ ] \ \ .   $$
Since the original equation tells us that the first factors on each side of the equation are equal, we can "cancel" them, leaving us with
$$ \Rightarrow \ \   \frac{d}{dx} \ [ \  y \ \ln (x)  \ ] \  \ = \ \  \frac{d}{dx} \ [ \  x \ \ln (y)  \ ] \ \ . $$
So the "jump" directly to applying the natural logarithm (or, really, the logarithm with any acceptable base) to both sides of the equation is simply an unspoken economy.

Answer (score 0):

1. > it took the log of both sides and then it implicitly differentiates... isn't that wrong since we are changing the
   > function to something different?
   >
   > That part I understand but why does... make it equivalent to $y\ln(x)=x\ln(y)\,?$

   It is always valid to perform the same operation to both sides of an
   equation; the equality of left and right sides continues to hold
   (i.e., the new relationship continues to apply to the original
   variable tuple).

   Note that the resulting equation may not be *equivalent* to the
   original one, and may not be *useful*. For example, it is valid to
   multiply $x^y=y^x$ by $0,$ but the new equation $0=0$ is clearly
   useless for determining $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}.$

   Note also that the resulting equation need **not** be equivalent to
   the original one in order to be useful. For example, $$\ln x=\ln
   y\implies x=y\implies \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=1,$$ even though
   there are some $(x,y)$ for which $x=y
   {\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies} \ln x=\ln y.$
2. In the [given exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/548347/21813), for $x,y>0,$ $$x^y=y^x\iff y\ln x = x \ln
   y\implies\ldots\iff \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\dfrac {y(x 
   \ln y - y)}{x(y \ln x - x)};$$ the *first* step's equivalence is because $\ln$ is
   an injective function, as explained in Eric's answer.